# Visual Studio for Web 2012 inline aspx code if-selection does not work

Tags: c#

I have a problem with writing a very simple code for Visual Studio 2012 for Web. I followed an example in a Book and did everything just as they did but the programm does not work. I am getting a message, that a `;` is missing. This is the first part of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>WebFormularKontrolle</title>
<%@ page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
void page_load()
{
    double z1, z2, z;

    If(IsPostBack)
    {
        Validate();

        If(IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                z1 = Convert.ToDouble(zahl1.Value);
            }
            catch
            {
                z1 = 0;
            }
            try
            {
                z2 = Convert.ToDouble(zahl2.Value);
            }
            catch
            {
                z2 = 0;




     }

            z = z1 + z2;
        }
    }
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Addieren</p>

<form id="Form1" runat="server">

    <p><input runat="server" id="zahl1" /> Zahl 1
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
        ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
        ControlToValidate="zahl1"
        Display="Dynamic"
        runat="server">
        Bitte eintragen
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator></p>

    <p><input runat="server" id="zahl2" /> Zahl 1
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
        ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
        ControlToValidate="zahl2"
        Display="Dynamic"
        runat="server">
        Bitte eintragen
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator></p>

    <p><input id="Submit1" runat="server"
    type="submit" value="Senden" /></p>
</form>

<p><asp:Label ID="ergebnis" runat="server" /></p>
```

I hope someone can help me. And please try to explain the problem to me in a simple way, I am a total beginner in Visual Studio.
Thank you!!

Edit: Now here's the full code. The error is at the line "If(IsPostBack) and if I delete this line, the next if-line sone lines below gives an error.

Comment: On which line of your code are you getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Validate initially to force asterisks
        // to appear before the first roundtrip.
        Validate();
    }
}
```

I guess it should be something like above code block. Correct me if i am wrong!

And i totally agree with @Darin Dimitrov